# QGIS3 Python Export PNG after layout resize

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-print-layouts, qgis-3

I have maps being created that have nice colour banding on them for the contours.

I want to be able to export the legend for that colour banding as an image so it can be imported into another application.

My solution was to create a print layout containing the appropraite legend in it, then use the exportToImage function to save the file out.

This all seems to work, and the script reports success.. except no PNG file appears.  However if I manually press the **Resize To Contents** button on the layout, then the same exportToImage command works as expected.

[image: resize to contents]

This makes me think the layout size is somehow seen as 0,0 in size, and needs to have the output size defined.  I tired using what I think is the same resize function in python.  But there must be something else needs to be done as well.

I thought I got the same command sorted in my python below.. but clearly there is another step I'm missing somewhere. Hopefully an obvious one.

Here is the code I'm using with a couple of edits for clarity

```
##
## Begin Creating Print Layouts
##

project = QgsProject.instance()

#Create a new print layout
printLayout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
project.layoutManager().addLayout(printLayout)
printLayout.setName("Colour Band Legend")

#Get the list of all the pages in the layout
paperPages=QgsLayoutPageCollection(printLayout)

#Add a legend to the print layout
legend=QgsLayoutItemLegend(printLayout)
legend.setTitle("")
printLayout.addItem(legend)
legend.setAutoUpdateModel(False)
legItems=legend.model()

#some editing of the legend items.. skipped for brevity

#resize all the pages to fit around the now edited legend
paperPages.resizeToContents(QgsMargins(0,0,0,0),QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters)
printLayout.reloadSettings()


#Save the layout to a png file
legendExportPath="C:/Test.png"
print("Saving " + legendExportPath)

legendExporter=QgsLayoutExporter(printLayout)
imageSettings=legendExporter.ImageExportSettings()
imageSettings.cropToContents=True
imageSettings.dpi=300
imageSettings.pages=[0]
legendExporter.exportToImage(legendExportPath,imageSettings)
```

Comment: I have a very very cludgy solution.  I discovered that I didn't need the manual resizeLayoutToContent if I just opened and closed the layout designer I could fix the issue.  So I added lines to open an close the layout manager in code just before doing the export.  `designerWindow=iface.openLayoutDesigner(printLayout)` then `designerWindow.close()`